# Jquery dynamic div slides

Tags: jquery

So I was working on creating a Jquery slideshow with divs (just using text).

I have a fiddle here to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/g13y67ef/

The problem I have is I'd like to be able to do it in a way much easier to understand.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    $('#slide_1').click(function () {
    $('#slide_1').fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $('#slide_2').fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $('#slide_2').click(function () {           
                $('#slide_2').fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $('#sldie_3').fadeIn("slow", function () {
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

What could I do besides this indefinite nesting (say I wanted to add 10 slides)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic function for your task, you can add as many slides as you want provided that they follow the same pattern in `id`:

```
$('div[id*="slide"]').click(function () {//any div that contains `slide` in its id
    var index = $(this).index();//get the index of the current item
    var size = $('div[id*="slide"]').length;//get the total number of divs in the html to traverse
    $(this).hide();//hide current item        
    index++;//move to the next item        
    if(index < size)//if not the last item
    {
        $('div[id*="slide"]').eq(index).fadeIn('slow');//show the next item

    }else{
        $('div[id*="slide"]').eq(0).fadeIn('slow');//go to the first item           
    }              
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/g13y67ef/2/